# Django Model field as formfield in templates

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

I guess this is a simple question, but I am not being able to find a definitive answer whether this is possible or not.

I have a Model object that is being passed to my template during rendering. While I use most of the Model fields to show their values, I came across a need to show a few of them as formfields (with their respective HTML element like rendered via ModelForms). Can ModelForm class usage be avoided here and simply use the Model's field to be rendered as formfield directly from template?

an example:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    month = models.PositiveIntegerField(_('Month'), choices=MONTH_CHOICES)
    year = models.PositiveIntegerField(_('Year'))
```

Now in template based on the above Model example I want to show the year as a value but month as a dropdown with selected current value?

Any pointer appreciated!

Use case:

Imagine a generic list_view like case where you are rendering a queryset. What you have there is object per iteration, however on the list view you want to allow your users to perform some quick editing of few object attributes to avoid forcing them to go to full edit mode (maybe via simple ajax).

Comment: Why do you want to avoid using `ModelForm`? It is the right tool here.

Comment: I guess I should have given some more insight why and where this can be useful.

Imagine a generic list_view like case where you are rendering a queryset. Now what you have there is object per iteration, however on the list view you want to allow your users to perform some quick editing of few object attributes to avoid forcing them to go to full edit mode. I hope this clarifies my needs.

Comment: List of modelfoms is the solution here. You can acces the model itself with `{{ form.instance }}`

Comment: I think I can write a simple template tag that creates a FormModel with the given field on the fly, but I would like first to make sure there is no standard way of solving this in template first.
Honestly, list of ModelForms really looks overengineering for my task I think...

Comment: And how are you going to process the form you've created in template?

Comment: I haven't tried this but my hope is to return the form field itself from template tag and have it rendered normally in template.

Comment: OK, you've rendered form, what next? You need to process it, right? To process form, you need view. And you need a form object in your view. That means that you need create a form instance and there is no overengineering here.

Comment: Oh ok...My plan is to use a simple ajax view to make the change...I can skip the form for my simple case...

My only concern with using list of ModelForms is I will need to change my view handling as well as walk thru couple of hundred lines of written template to adjust referncing items via instance.

Besides, generic views will no longer help me to shorten my views.

Comment: Template tag will require same amount to work, but it's less clear and more error-prone. And is there any problem to find and replace something even in millions of lines with any modern text editor? And you can always learn sed.

Comment: Are you judging my sed skills based on my question, my judgment or my reputation point on this site? :) Don't get this offensive my friend, I trully appreciate all your feedback. The reason of my post was to see whether I am missing anything that is done in a common way to solve this task.

Comment: Then, if you know sed, it won't be a problem to "walk thru couple of hundred lines of written template to adjust referncing items via instance".

Answer (score 0):

No.

As canvassed in the comments, this is not possible. A model, and its fields do not know about forms - that is what forms, and modelforms are for.

The right way to do this is to wrap your model objects with a modelform, which you can adjust (using inheritance) to do whatever you want with the non-form fields, if you wish to make this more transparent.

Creating modelforms in the template means that you have nowhere to process the forms in django. Apparently you want to interface them with some kind of ajax interface, so perhaps this is not a problem for you, but in any case, I fail to see how it would be *easier* than simply creating the modelforms in the view.